# misreading url path as params

Tags: node.js, express

I have faced upon a problem which may sound weird but lot of people must be dealing with.

I have defined two routes in my `routes.js` file.

**Route1**
`router.route('/atpages/:query')
   .get(app.oauth.authorise(), atpagesController.getAtpagesByIdOrName);`

**Route2**
`router.route('/atpages/match')
   .get(app.oauth.authorise(), atpagesController.matchAtpagesByUrl);`

Both the routes are supposed to call different functions in controller, but the issue is whenever i hit **Route2** automatically **Route1** is being called. 
I know the issue that it is considering `match` as a query, my problem is that i need the routes to hit different questions without redefining their endpoints.

What i want is route should remain the same as they are but they should hit respective functions only.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if query is not equal *match* in Route 1 controller like this:

```
function getAtpagesByIdOrName (req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.query == 'match') {
        next();
    }
}
```

Comment: but then if i really want to pass `match` in my query, it will misbehave, this would be like restricting the functionality which i dont want.